# Принцип работы интерфейсных переменных в Java

Tags: java, ооп

Только начал изучать Java, поэтому вопрос скорее всего глупый. Пример кода из Хорстманна:

```
public class TimerTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter();

    // construct a timer that calls the listener
    // once every 10 seconds
    Timer t = new Timer(10000, listener);
    t.start();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quit program?");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}

class TimePrinter implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + now);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
  }
}
```

Почему в данной строчке используется интерфейсная переменная? Почему не объектная? Что за процесс происходит?

```
ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если в будущем вы захотите использовать не `TimePrinter`, а другую реализацию `ActionListener`? Конечно, можно делать как вам вздумается. А сделано для того, чтобы можно было на лету менять конечную реализацию (к примеру, вместо `TimePrinter`  использовать `MsecTimePrinter`, т.е. другую реализацию интерфейса `ActionListener`).

Поэтому и принято оперировать интерфейсами. Чтобы не связывать свой код жестко конкретными реализациями, т.к. в интерфейс можно присвоить любой класс, который реализует данный интерфейс. Это ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ подход к написанию кода

А процесс происходит довольно простой: вы объявляете интерфейсную переменную типа `ActionListener` и связываете её с объектом `TimePrinter`. В последующем вы используете только методы интерфейса `ActionListener`, что освобождает вас от знания конкретной реализации самого класса `TimePrinter`.

Answer (score 3):

То на что Вы указали есть реализация одного из принципов ООП(ООД), а конкретно "принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков". Обычно данный принцип объединяют c 4-мя другими и называют акронимом SOLID. 
Суть принципа заключается в следующем везде, где используют базовый тип, есть возможность использовать подтипы базового типа, при этом с точки зрения кода не имеет значения, работает ли он с базовым или дочерним типом.

В приведенном примере этот принцип проявляется в двух местах:

```
1) ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter();
2) Timer(10000, listener);
```